# Solving congruences like $3^p\equiv 1\pmod{\! p}$, $p$ prime [order computation]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

In particular, I've used python to brute-force results of $3^n-1\bmod{7} = 0$ but was hoping there is a more elegant method.

Comment: Do you notice a pattern in the solutions $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $p\neq 3$, Fermat's little theorem gives:

$$3^{p-1}-1\equiv 0\pmod{p}$$

Thus $n=p-1$ is a solution. It follows that all multiples of $p-1$ are also solutions. Clearly for $p=3$ the only solution is $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You know from [Fermat’s little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) that $3^{p-1}\bmod p=1$ if $p$ is a prime greater than $3$. There may be smaller solutions: $3^5\bmod 11=1$, for instance. However, they must divide $p-1$, so there’s only a limited number to try. Once you find the minimum solution $m$, you have all solutions: they’re the positive integer multiples of $m$.

Comment: Out of interest, is there any constraint one can apply to the possible smaller solutions (to avoid trial and error)?

Comment: @J.G.: I don’t know of one.

Comment: @j.g.:no; it's the "discrete logarithm"-problem. What you can do to reduce the trial-and-error effort is to factorize $p-1$ because the "cycle-length" must be a divisor of $p-1$ But as far as I know you can't do less...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Thanks for the info.

Comment: @J.G. As far as I know the question of when $3$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ is open. Any method which would tell you which is the smallest such $n$ would be a stronger result than the question of primitive roots....

Answer (score 0):

For the state-of-the-art on the order computation problem see Andrew Sutherland's 2007 MIT Thesis [Order Computations in Generic Groups](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/cis/theses/sutherland-phd.pdf). Below is an excerpt from p. 14.

[image]
[image]