# Solving for solutions to a congruence

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I am interested in solutions to this congruence:

$$2^kx \equiv x \bmod m$$

Where $m$ and $x$ are known positive integers. They may not necessarily be prime or coprime. I am looking for solutions for $k$. How can I do this?

Comment: How about the cancellation law to cancel the $x$s first?

Comment: I don't know the cancellation law, or if it's even valid, because dividing both sides by $x$ would mean it would need to have a multiplicative inverse modulo $m$ which may not always be true

Comment: Here is a formal proof https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Common_Factor_Cancelling_in_Congruence

Comment: If, in the terms the proof uses $x=a=b\equiv x (\text{mod}  m)$ then $2^{k}\equiv1 (\text{mod}  {m \over d})$ where $d = \gcd \left\{{a, m}\right\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\,\ d = (M,X),\,\ m = M/d,\,\ x = X/d.\ $ Then

$\quad M\mid X(2^k\!-1)\!\!\overset{\ \div\,d}\iff m\mid x(2^k\!-1)\overset{(m,x)\,=\,1}\iff m\mid 2^k\!-1\iff {\rm ord}_m(2)\mid k$

Comment: My reading abilities are limited so this answer does not really make much sense to me.

Comment: @Remy What doesn't make sense?

Comment: I uppercased  m and x, and converted the congruence to divisibility form, then cancelled their gcd $\,d,\,$ then applied Euclid's Lemma.

Comment: @Remy See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/208293/242) for modular order algorithms.

Comment: @Remy If any steps remain unclear then let me know *precisely* where, so I can elaborate.